# Scriptcontrol - bind client & server properties

Tags: asp.net, scriptcontrol, msscriptcontrol

Is it possible to bind properties on the client and server side in Scriptcontrol, so when I set property in javascript, change will be visible also in code behind and when I set property in code behind, change will be visible in javascript?

I can't get it work like above - it is set initially, when I set property where scriptcontrol is declared, but when I change it later it is still the same as before...

EDIT: I try to do a ProgressBar for long postbacks in our ASP.NET application. I have tried many options but none works for me... I want to set progress value in code behind and has it updated in view during long task postback.

Code for ScriptControl:
C#:

```
public class ProgressBar : ScriptControl
{
    private const string ProgressBarType = "ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar";
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors()
    {
        this.Value = 100;
        this.Maximum = 90;
        var descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor(ProgressBarType, this.ClientID);

        descriptor.AddProperty("value", this.Value);
        descriptor.AddProperty("maximum", this.Maximum);

        yield return descriptor;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ScriptReference> GetScriptReferences()
    {
        yield return new ScriptReference("ProgressBar.cs.js");          
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
Type.registerNamespace("ProgressBarNamespace");

ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar = function(element) {
    ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar.initializeBase(this, [element]);
    this._value = 0;
    this._maximum = 100;
};

ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar.callBaseMethod(this, "initialize");
        this._element.Value = this._value;
        this._element.Maximum = this._maximum;

        this._element.show = function () {
            alert(this.Value);
        };
    },
    dispose: function () {
        ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar.callBaseMethod(this, "dispose");
    },
    get_value: function () {
        return this._value;
    },
    set_value: function (value) {
        if (this._value !== value) {
            this._value = value;
            this.raisePropertyChanged("value");
        }
    },
    get_maximum: function () {
        return this._maximum;
    },
    set_maximum: function (value) {
        if (this._maximum !== value) {
            this._maximum = value;
            this.raisePropertyChanged("maximum");
        }
    }
};

ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar.registerClass("ProgressBarNamespace.ProgressBar", Sys.UI.Control);
if (typeof (Sys) !== "undefined") Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

I'll appreciate any way to implement this progress bar...

Comment: I think your approach is the most elegant way to do this. I'm curious, did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do this often using hidden fields.
Bear in mind that hidden fields are not secure and may have other downfalls, since they don't actually hide their value, just simply do not display it.

ASPX Markup

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenRequest" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

ASPX.CS Code behind

```
    public string HiddenRequest
    {
        set
        {
            hiddenRequest.Value = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return hiddenRequest.Value;
        }
    }
```

Page JAVASCRIPT (with jQuery)

```
$('#hiddenRequest').val('MyResult');
```

This way, I can access the same field using one variable as such, accessed both from client side and server side.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is even possible in ScriptControl - there is no view part, it's only a class.

Comment: perhaps i misunderstood your question. can you please give a code sample of what you are trying to do and what isn't working as you expected?